# Get all matching substrings as an array with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

Hey so I am trying to get all the substrings that match a Regex in a string as an array.

Example string- `"[file/path/name.exe]value"` I need to get `[file/path/name.exe]` as the result.

Few more examples -

1. `"[file/path/name.exe][file/path/name1.exe]val"`
   Result - `["[file/path/name.exe]", "[file/path/name.exe]"]`
2. `"[file/path/name1.exe][value][file/path/name2.exe]some_value"`
   Result - `["[file/path/name1.exe]", "[file/path/name2.exe]"]`
3. `"[file/path/name1.exe]http:/\[file/path/name2.exe]some_value"` Result - `["[file/path/name1.exe]", "[file/path/name2.exe]"]`

So basically I need to extract anything that's between brackets [] and is a file path that ends with ".exe"

This is the Regex I tried so far -

```
let reg = new RegExp(/\[\S+\.exe\]/gi)
```

This gives the following results -
And `string.match()` function in java script to get the results as an array.

1. `"[file/path/name.exe]value"`
   Result - `["[file/path/name.exe]"]`. Works for this case.
2. But for this case, it doesn't work `"[file/path/name.exe][file/path/name1.exe]val"`
   I am getting this - `["[file/path/name.exe][file/path/name1.exe]"]` as one element.
3. And same for this case too `"[file/path/name1.exe][value][file/path/name2.exe]some_value"`
   I am getting this - `["[file/path/name1.exe][value][file/path/name2.exe]"]` as one string.

So I tried doing negative look ahead like there should be only one opening bracket "[". But that didn't workout.
Regex was - `let reg = new RegExp(/\[\S+\.exe\]$(?!\[)/gi)` but it doesn't work for any case.

I also tried to limit the word ".exe" to one but also didn't work.
Regex was-`let reg = new RegExp(/\[\S+\(\b\.exe\b){1}\]/gi)`

As you can see I am not an expert in Regex. Any pointers would be appreciated.
Thanks.

PS: Apologies for any formatting issues. Tried my best on a phone :-).

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+find+all+between+square+brackets+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Just find all stuff in square brackets and filter the result on stuff that has .exe https://regex101.com/r/LUVRYK/1

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lhp6fx19/

Comment: @mplungjan Yes I did post the Regex that I used and provided examples of what worked and what did not. Not sure why this has been down voted.

Comment: @mplungjan also I was hoping u would explain the Regex u wrote? Thanks.

Comment: I did - click the regex101 link

Comment: Downvote possibly due to missing example code - if you next time click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor you can make a [mcve] like I did in JSFiddle

Comment: @mplungjan ya thanks for the explanation couldn't see it in mobile view.

Comment: @mplungjan sorry to bother u so many times. But can u tell me what is wrong with this regex - /\[\S+(\b\.exe\b){1}\]/gi ? i am checking for any number of word characters with \S+ followed by a group (\b.exe\b) which includes a word ".exe" and it should occur only once- {1} and all of this is in between 2 square brackets -\[ \]. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I am not currently near a computer- use the regex101 to test your regex